# Why does command after if False produce an empty list in Perl 6 REPL?

Tags: raku

If the condition of `if` is `False`, instead of empty output, REPL gives `()` (an empty `List`?)

```perl6
> put 1 if True
1
> put 1 if False
()               # ← What is this?
```

What does `()` mean?

Answer (score 9):

In earlier versions of this endlessly edited answer I wrote that "The REPL isn't doing anything special". But of course I was wrong. The REPL evaluates a line of code. If it generates output, it displays that output and that's it. If it doesn't, it `say`s the value of the last statement. See [JJ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52641639/1077672).

The `()` you get means an empty list.

In earlier versions of this answer I agreed with you that it was an empty `List`. But of course I was wrong. In this instance it's a *subtype* of `List`. See [Brad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52637642/1077672).)

---

Arguably I'd best just delete this answer. :)

The following is what remains of possible value to this answer until someone else explains what else I've got wrong...

## What Raku is doing

A statement evaluates to a value.

A statement can be just an expression.

An expression can be just a literal value:

```
> 42
42
```

A literal list of values evaluates to a `List`:

```
> 42, 99
(1 99)
```

An empty list is displayed as `()`. This can mean either an empty `List`:

```
> ()
()            # <-- empty `List`
> List.new
()            # <-- empty `List`
> 'aa' ~~ m:g/b/
()            # <-- empty `List`
```

or an empty list that's a sub-type of `List`, but which reuses the same stringification, e.g. a `Slip`:

```
> Empty
()            # <-- empty `Slip`
> Slip.new
()            # <-- empty `Slip`
```

Statements can also evaluate to a single value:

```
> if True { 42 }
42
```

or a list:

```
> if True { 42, 99 }
(42 99)
```

Some statements evaluate to an empty list. Your question is one such example:

```
> if False {}
()
```

As Brad points out, that's an empty `Slip`, specifically the `Empty` instance.

Comment: I guessed it was an empty list, but still don't fully understand its meaning.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I understand it better! I think, it seems very probable -- something that is in essence nothing, but nevertheless shows up in REPL.

Comment: @raiph When something seems to me strange or unexpected, it usually means that I just don't understand the reason behind it. So now I'll know, that `()` is a way of showing that there is no output.

Comment: @EugeneBarsky "So now I'll know, that `()` is a way of showing that there is no output." Either that, or the output is an empty list. I've edited my answer a zillion times trying to nail this slippery notion down.

Answer (score 7):

Actually your question is incorrect.

What you really get back is an empty [Slip](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Slip.html).
Specifically, you get back a specific instance of it that is called [Empty](https://docs.perl6.org/syntax/Empty).

So it does in fact give you an [Empty](https://docs.perl6.org/syntax/Empty) output.

TLDR; It returns [Empty](https://docs.perl6.org/syntax/Empty) because it has to return something, and an empty [Slip](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Slip.html) is more useful in list operations than any other "empty" value.

---

What [Slip](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Slip.html) does is insert itself into the outer listy value.

```perl6
say (1, 2, 3, (4, 5)).perl;
# (1, 2, 3, (4, 5))

say (1, 2, 3, (4, 5).Slip).perl;
# (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

The reason for the existence of [Slip](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Slip.html) is that [Perl 6](https://perl6.org) doesn't flatten values by default.

```perl6
sub return-list () { 4, 5 }

say (1, 2, 3, return-list()).perl;
# (1, 2, 3, (4, 5))
```

(Before the official release it used to flatten values in some cases, and it was both confusing and difficult to work-around)

So the feature of [Slip](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Slip.html) was introduced for instances where you really did want it to flatten.

```perl6
sub return-slip () { slip 4, 5 }

say (1, 2, 3, return-slip()).perl;
# (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Note that it only does one level of flattening.

```perl6
sub return-structured-slip () {
   slip 4, (5,)
}

say (1, 2, 3, return-structured-slip()).perl;
# (1, 2, 3, 4, (5,))
```

---

This is really useful to do a [`grep`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/grep) as a part of [`map`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/map) code.

```perl6
say (0..10).map: { $_, $_² if .is-prime }
# ((2 4) (3 9) (5 25) (7 49))
```

---

It can also be used for leaving off values when calling a routine.

```perl6
my $a;
my $b = 1;

say(
  ( $a.perl if $a ),
  ( $b.perl if $b ),
)
```

---

One useful feature of singular [Empty](https://docs.perl6.org/syntax/Empty), is that you can match against it.

```perl6
multi sub foo ($_){.say}
multi sub foo (Empty){ say 'Hello, World' }

foo Empty; # Hello, World

foo (1 if 0); # Hello, World
```

Note that it is possible to get an empty [Slip](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Slip.html) that is not the singular value [Empty](https://docs.perl6.org/syntax/Empty). In which case it will not match.

```perl6
|()
().Slip
```

Answer (score 6):

It is returned value empty `Slip` (`Empty`). Try

```perl6
 say {put 1 if False}() ~~ Empty
```

You can use that `… if False` return `Empty` with `List`:

```perl6
 dd (2..100).map: { $_² if .is-prime }
```

Similarly, `… with Nil` and `Nil andthen …` return `Empty`.

Answer (score 5):

All answers so far are excellent, explaining what's going on under the hood. But I'll try to answer your question directly.

> If the condition of if is False, instead of empty output, REPL gives () (an empty List?)

The key to this is that you're working on the REPL. The REPL prints the output of a block if there's some; if there's no output, it prints whatever the expression returns. Let's then deal with your two options as blocks; what is inside the parentheses is what you would actually type in the REPL:

```
say (put 1 if True).^name # OUTPUT: «1␤Bool␤»
```

That's right. The REPL will see the output, `1`, and print that. The block result, `True` in this case since that's what `put` returns, is dropped by the REPL. What happens in the second case?

```
say (put 1 if False).^name # OUTPUT: «Slip␤»
```

In this case, there's no output. The REPL would take `(put 1 if False)` as an expression, and prints `()` which, in this case, is a Slip. As indicated in @raiph answer, that's what `if False {}` returns, so that's what you get in your REPL.

Comment: @raiph thanks for drawing this to my attention anyway. I've edited a bit the answer; I hope it's a bit clearer now...